# How can I identify the field data types returned by a RESTful Web API?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a RESTful Web API in ASP.NET.  It is returning data from my SQL Server database.  How can I identify the data types of the fields that  are returned in AngularJS?  The reason I want this is because I'm creating a simple interface to load data in an edit form one of many tables that is selected at run time.  I don't want to build a custom edit form for each table.  It's working, but I want to clean up the interface like displaying boolean values in a checkbox or formatting the appearance of date types.  Do I need to return the data in XML to do this or is there some other way?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, like: Array.isArray(data),typeof(data)..

Comment: Well, if you want to know the data types, you need metadata. You either get that from the service or from the data itself. This is quite a broad question. Please do some research into this and come back if you have specific questions.

Comment: Ved, I tried typeof like this "alert(typeof($scope.TableData.CreatedDate));" and it returned string, which I suppose is the type in JSON, but the underlying database has a type of DateTime.  It looks like the Web API doesn't return the data type so I may have to do what Mike is suggesting, build some way for the service to return the metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using SqlConnection.GetSchema and SMO objects for the foreign keys.